# MVC4 Ajax.ActionLink send UpdateTargetId to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making serious asp.net mvc ajax request using Ajax.ActionLink.

But requesting same url from server i may fill different html container (UpdateTargetId).
Everything is ok, but i need to know serverside what view should i return.

I watched fiddler and didn't find anything about UpdateTargetId value.
Then i realized that i can add some data in OnBegin javascript method but i don't know UpdateTargetId there too.

So now i'm using hack with different http methods (like post and get) but i'd like to find less hacky solution.

Comment: your question is a little confusing, but from what I understood you can create a partial view and update that view using an ajax/json call using a jquery

Comment: Can you post your controllor action and View code along with question

Comment: I'll update answer a bit later but there is nothing to show in code it's almost basic asp.net mvc to call Ajax.ActionLink(... OnBegin = "SomeJsFunc", UpdateTargetId = "someId" ... ), and to get UpdateTargetId in controller or in javascript function SomeJsFunc what fires on before request will go to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not complete and still hacky but maybe the only way

in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js just changed

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.href,
            type: "GET",
            data: []
        });
    });
```

to

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.href,
            type: "GET",
            data: [{ name: "targerId", value: this.getAttribute("data-ajax-update") }]
        });
    });
```

or add another push in asyncRequest method:

```
...
options.data.push({ name: "X-Requested-With", value: "XMLHttpRequest" });
options.data.push({ name: "targerId", value: element.getAttribute("data-ajax-update") });
...
```

I don't want to change unobtrusive code and changed Ajax.ActionLink to custom ActionLink that use different flag to fire ajax request (for example a[data-customajax=true]") to separate them.
If someone have questions for these answer i would be glad to help you!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding this question properly, you probably want to do something like the following in your view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="testid" class='blah'></div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show Test Options", "ShowTestOptions", "Test", new { theVariableIWant = "Test" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "testid", HttpMethod = "GET" })
```

And then in your controller have something like:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   public PartialViewResult ShowTestOptions(string theVariableIWant)
   {
        ///Perform whatever operations you need to here.
        return PartialView();
   }
}
```

More detail would be appreciated though.

Comment: Yes, thats right but i can't see solution here... I need to get testid serverside.

Comment: I updated with a general method for passing a variable into the server side controller.  If you have an integer you need to pass, update it accordingly (i.e. theVariableIwant = whatever value you want).  If you have multiple values, you should just be able to add more values to the dictionary.  Let me know if this solves your problem.

Edit: You may need to post it as well, I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh, sorry for being not clear. I forgot to write one more time important point that it is single page up and i need to have clear links (without internal params as theVariableIWant) until i'll update url using history api. Surely i can cut querystring param theVariableIWant while processing url, but i'd like to have clean href on links, anyway thank you